# Docker compose Mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

i tried to do 2 changes on my docker-compose, but i'm didn't find how to do it.
1- I want to create 2 users.
2- I want to import a sql file from docker-compose.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0.21
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        container_name: mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_USER="user, user2"
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD="pass, pass2"
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=templateProject
            - MYSQL_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=1024M
            - MYSQL_INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE=1G
            - MYSQL_INNODB_LOG_FILE_SIZE=256M
            - MYSQL_INNODB_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE=256M
        ports:
            - '3361:3360'
        volumes:
            - ./dump.sql:/my_dump.sql
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        environment:
          - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2 you should bind mount the directory containing your sql file like this:

```
"./folderwithsql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
```

For #1 You may be able to include another sql file in your "folderwithsql" mount that includes SQL statements to create the extra user.  The file would contain something similar to these:

```
CREATE USER 'extrauser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordforextrauser';
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE ON mynewdb.* TO 'extrauser'@'%';
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your reply.
I did what you said, but didn't work :(

Comment: Did it not run any of your sql scripts or did it just not create the extra user?

Comment: Any script...
i put this into dump.sql

-- --
-- -- Use database.
USE `templateProject`;


CREATE TABLE `tblAction` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `FK_activeID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: volumes:
            - "/Users/gustavo/Desktop/mysqldump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"